# OnMessage i want to open Google Play android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I get notification from GCM, When i get notification, i want to show google play to install app.

Im trying like this

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.karya.kot"));
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,                 notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify( 0, notification);
```

But when i click the notification, its not going to google play? What i did wrong?

Comment: where did you start the `activity`?

Comment: Directly start the activity from pending intent, is that possible?

Comment: oh sorry my bad..your code should be working then

Comment: you are testing on `emulator`? It will not open the market in `emulator` as it does not have `Google Play`

Comment: Im testing in device, when i click notification im not able to access play

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this code in my mobile and it is working

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int sb2value = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Testomg", System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.karya.kot"));
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Google Play", "Download app", intent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```