# Notification not working with Android 4.0

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OnMessage i want to open Google Play android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738750/onmessage-i-want-to-open-google-play-android)

When I use the below code in Android 4.0 (ICS) it doesn't work:

```
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Testomg", System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.karya.kot"));
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Google Play", "Download app", intent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

But it's works for lower versions of Android.

For Android ICS, I want to use Notification.Builder, but then what should I use for lower versions?

Comment: You could try using [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) from the Support Library

Comment: any Error or What log cat says

Comment: ya you are correct, if i use  NotificationCompat.Builder, then how do i get Notification, im using notification = builder.getNotification(), but its showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is full working code for me on any version of the android 2.2 and above

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, <nameofactivity>.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }
```

Comment: it will work on Android ICS? then what is the use of Notification.Builder? please explain me about this?

Comment: Yes..it will work on Android ICS. Notification.Builder is wrapper around the code which I wrote but why i wrote the code because you are trying to use the NotificationMamanger

Comment: ya you are correct, if i use NotificationCompat.Builder, then how do i get Notification, im using notification = builder.getNotification(), but its showing error, please give me an example of using NotificationCompat.Builder which will support all the version of android